# Lambda Proguard R8, How keep lambda?

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8

```
com.onesignal.-$$Lambda$OSInAppMessagePushPrompt$mIb8tlhn4VMS1tXne5sef5zwUzc -> f.g.a:
    com.onesignal.OneSignal$OSPromptActionCompletionCallback f$0 -> a
    1:3:void com.onesignal.OSInAppMessagePushPrompt.lambda$handlePrompt$0(com.onesignal.OneSignal$OSPromptActionCompletionCallback,boolean):13:15 -> response
    1:3:void response(boolean):0 -> response
```

How can I make it so that R8 does not rename the lambda expression to the onesignal libraries.
It does not help: `-keep class com.onesignal.** { *; }`

Comment: The keep rule you have `-keep class com.onesignal.** { *; }` should keep everything in the `com.onesignal` namespace which is in the input. So if the class `com.onesignal.-$$Lambda$OSInAppMessagePushPrompt$mIb8tlhn4VMS1tXne5sef5zwUzc` is in you input it should survive to the output. Please file an issue with the R8 project at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788 providing details of your setup including version of AGP/R8 and if possible the onesignal library.

Comment: It does not work to me either...